# Move instead of copy for boost::dynamic_bitset BlockInputIterator constructor?

Tags: c++, boost

Would it be possible to create another `boost::dynamic_bitset` BlockInputIterator constructor to use move instead of copy for `std::vector`?

I believe the following constructor uses copy [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#cons4):

```
template <typename BlockInputIterator>
dynamic_bitset(
    BlockInputIterator first,
    BlockInputIterator last,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Here is some code that I wrote to show what I'm asking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Notice the vector opposed to dynamic_bitset
    vector<uint8_t> data;

    // put in dummy data
    data.push_back(0x1a);
    data.push_back(0xcf);
    data.push_back(0xfc);
    data.push_back(0x1d);
    for (auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
    {
      cout << hex << (int)*i << dec << ' ';
    }
    cout << std;
    cout << "data.data(): " << hex << (uint64_t)data.data() << dec << endl;

    // I believe this is a copy opposed to a move
    boost::dynamic_bitset<uint8_t> bs0(data.begin(), data.end());

    // I would like to be able to do this which would use move,
    // is that possible considering the vector?
    boost::dynamic_bitset<uint8_t> bs1 = data;

    return 0;
}
```

So basically I'm wondering if boost could add an additional constructor to `boost::dynamic_bitset` to use move instead of copy for `std::vector`?

Comment: It should not be hard to propose a feature and PR it. I would, however I know beforehand they'll want to accommodate C++03 with BOOST_MOVE and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Yes I wanted to propose an additional to the library but wanted to make sure it was even possible first. :)

Comment: It's not simple at first (and with the iterators it won't work, but I assume you wouldn't mind moving from containers instead?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless `vector` gets a change to its interface.

See, movement is a very intimate operation for an object; that's why move support requires member functions of that type. It's not something you can force onto an object from outside.

`vector` has no way to adopt an arbitrary, user-allocated buffer of memory as its internal storage. It theoretically could be required to do so via some means, but it does not have such an interface at present. Without such support, other code cannot give `std::vector` its memory.

Boost might be able to give `boost::container::vector` such an interface. But that would not change `std::vector`.

Likewise, you can't abscond with a `std::vector`'s memory storage. Well, you could, but only through allocator trickery. That is, you'd have to tell the allocator not to actually deallocate the allocation or destroy objects when it is told to do so by `vector`. That's going to be tricky, since `vector::get_allocator` returns a copy of the allocator.

Of course, `dynamic_bitset` doesn't have any way to be given an allocation either; it expects to own it. Much like `vector`. So even if you could abscond with `std::vector`'s storage, `dynamic_bitset` can't adopt it.

Comment: I was wondering if `std::vector` could be moved into `boost::dynamic_bitset` not the other way around, which I think is what you are saying. I was thinking that since the constructor get initialized with `std::vector` it would take that on underneath and thus have that intimacy you are describing.

Comment: @bantl23: Added notation about that.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! I had one other question. If `boost::dynamic_bitset` was implemented by inheriting and/or encapsulating `std::vector` would it then be possible?